# mysql regexp have a digit but not start with negative

Tags: mysql, regex

i have rows with values like `-4,3,2,1` and `3,2,1` or `3` or `2`

i need to select any row that have value `2` including the row with value `3,2,1` but not the one that have - at begining.

thank guys

Answer (score 1):

Why a regex?

```
SELECT ..
WHERE LEFT(yourfield, 1) <> '-'
  AND (
    (yourfield = 2) OR
    (yourfield LIKE '2,%') OR
    (yourfield LIKE '%,2,%') OR
    (yourfield LIKE '%,2')
 )
```

and then while you're trying to figure out why the WHERE is so complicated, you should go read up about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to do this with `like`:

```
select *
from t
where concat(',', col, ',') like '%,2,%' and
      col not like '-%'
```

If you are looking for "2", but not delimited by commas, then:

```
select *
from t
where instr(col, '2') > 0 and col not like '-%'
```

To get a column that does not start with a minus sign and constains a "2":

```
where col regexp '^[^-]*2*'
```

If the commas are important, the following should work:

```
where concat(',', col, ',') regexp ',^[^-]*,2,*'
```

Comment: thanks man..i know how to do it with like but i need with regexp and only one

Answer (score 0):

the best solution and the simplest that i could find:

```
where sponsored regexp '^[^-]*[1-2]'
```